# Get string inside quotation marks in command line/awk

Tags: windows, command-line, awk, command-line-arguments, gawk

I have created a command line script that will extract the lines from a file with the string "lines", but I only want to get the numbers inside the (").
For example I have the following lines

```
lines="188"
lines="24"
lines="24"
```

How can I get get the numbers inside the quotation marks (" ") so that my output would be

```
188
24
24
```

I want to achieve this using Windows command line or awk running on a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```
awk -F'\"' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: You could shorten it some `awk -F\" '{print $2}'`

Comment: I have output `"/path/1 x" "/path/2 x"` which i want to put into its own variables "a" and "b". Awk "print $1" does not output "/path/1 x" ...